# Baseball Menu Insertion sort part

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I'm trying to use insertion sort to sort for the batting average of the players. I get an error message  "The method get(int) in the type java.util.ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (double)" on the lines of S.get(outer) and S.get(inner - 1)

What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class menu {
  public static void main (String [] arg) throws IOException
  {

    PlayerRip.PlayerInfo obj5 = new PlayerRip.PlayerInfo();
    ArrayList<Player> obj6 = new ArrayList<Player>();
    MainMenu(obj5, obj6);


  }
  public static void MainMenu(PlayerRip P,  ArrayList<Player> S) throws IOException 
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int response = 0;
    int response2 = 0;

    ArrayList<Player> obj1 = new ArrayList<Player>();
    obj1.add(new Player("Agostini", "Aldo", "Pitcher", 170, 20, 72, 12, 6, 1, 1, 0));  
    do 
    {
      System.out.println("1. Open A file:");
      System.out.println("7. Exit the program");
      response = keyboard.nextInt();

      switch (response)
      {
        case 1:
        {
          openFile(obj1);

          do
          {
            System.out.println("2. Display all players");
            System.out.println("3. Enter player's Height");
            System.out.println("4. Sort all players alphabetically by Surname");
            System.out.println("5. Sort all players by batting average");
            System.out.println("6. Delete a player by selecting the player's surname from a list");
            System.out.println("7. Add a player to the stats");
            System.out.println("8. Save stats to a file");
            System.out.println("9. Exit the program");
            response2 = keyboard.nextInt();
            switch (response2)
            {
              case 2:
              {
                displayInfo(obj1);
                break;
              }
              case 3:
              {
                changeHeight(obj1);
                break;
              }
              case 4:
              {
                BubbleSort(obj1);
                break;
              }
              case 5:
              {
                break;
              }
              case 6:
              {
                deletePlayerInfo(obj1);
                break;
              }
              case 7:
              {
                addPlayerInfo(obj1);
                break;
              }
              case 8:
              {
                saveFile(obj1);
                break;
              }
              case 9:
              {
                System.exit(0);
                break;
              }

            }
          } while (response2 != 9);
          break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
          System.exit(0);
          break;
        }
      } 
    } while (response != 1 || response != 7);  // End of switch statement

  }
  public static void displayInfo(ArrayList<Player> S) {
    System.out.printf("%10s %10s %10s \t %4s %4s \t %4s \t %4s %4s \t %4s %4s %4s \n", "Surname", "GivenName", "Postition", "Height(cm)", "Hits", "AtBats", "Singles", "Doubles", "Triples", "HomeRuns", "Batting Average");
    for (int index = 0; index < S.size(); index++)
      S.get(index).displayInfo();
  }

  public static void openFile(ArrayList<Player> S) throws IOException // This method allows the oepning of files into the program
  {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName;
    S.removeAll(S); // Empties the list readies it for a new oned


    System.out.println("Enter a file name to open: ");
    fileName = userInput.next().trim();
    File file = new File(fileName);

    if (file.exists()) // Checks whether or not the file exists in the directory
    {
      Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);
      while (fileInput.hasNext())
      {
        S.add(new Player(fileInput.next(), fileInput.next(), fileInput.next(), fileInput.nextInt(), fileInput.nextInt(), fileInput.nextInt(), fileInput.nextInt(), fileInput.nextInt(), fileInput.nextInt(), fileInput.nextInt(), fileInput.nextDouble())); // If it exists it adds the token values into the respective lists 
      } 
      fileInput.close(); // Closes further file input
    }
    else // Error message incase the file-name is not valid 
      System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND");




  }  

  public static void saveFile(ArrayList<Player> S) throws IOException // This method allows for the saving of values to an external file
  {
    Scanner inputInfo = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName;
    System.out.println("Enter a file name to save the info with:");
    fileName = inputInfo.next().trim();
    File file = new File(fileName);
    PrintStream writeFile = new PrintStream(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++) // Gathers all values and prints them to the file in their respective format
    {
      writeFile.print(S.get(i).getName() + "  "); 
      writeFile.print(S.get(i).getName2() + "  ");
      writeFile.print(S.get(i).getPosition() + "  ");
      for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        writeFile.print(S.get(i).getMark(j) + "  ");
      for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        writeFile.print(S.get(i).getBatAvg(j));
      writeFile.println(" ");  
    }  
    writeFile.close(); // Stops any further writing to the file 
  } 

  public static void deletePlayerInfo(ArrayList<Player> S) // THis method allows the user to delete any player within the list
  {
    int deleteIt = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please select the number of the player to be deleted: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++) // Displays only the first/surNames of the players
    {
      System.out.print(i + ". " + S.get(i).getName());
      System.out.println(" ");
    }
    deleteIt = keyboard.nextInt();
    S.remove(deleteIt);
  }

  public static void addPlayerInfo(ArrayList<Player> S) // This method allows the user to add a new player to the list
  {
    String firstName = "";
    String surName = "";
    String posName = "";
    int heightVal = 0;
    int hitsVal = 0;
    int atBatsVal = 0;
    int singVal = 0;
    int doubVal = 0;
    int tripVal = 0;
    int homeVal = 0;


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // Various user input
    System.out.println("Enter the surname and name of the new player: ");
    System.out.println("Surname: ");
    surName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Name: ");
    firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the position of the new player: ");
    System.out.println("Position: ");
    posName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the height of the new player: ");
    heightVal = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the batting statistics: ");
    System.out.println("Hits: ");
    hitsVal = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("AtBats: ");
    atBatsVal = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Singles: ");
    singVal = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Doubles: ");
    doubVal = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Triples: ");
    tripVal = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("HomeRuns: ");
    homeVal = keyboard.nextInt();
    S.add(new Player(surName, firstName, posName, heightVal, hitsVal, atBatsVal, singVal, doubVal, tripVal, homeVal, 0));
  }

  public static void changeHeight(ArrayList<Player> S) 
  {
    int playerSel = 0;
    int newHeight = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // Various user input
    System.out.println("Select a player to enter the height for: ");

    do 
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++) // Displays only the first/surNames of the players
      {
        System.out.print(i + ". " + S.get(i).getName());
        System.out.println(" "); 
      }
      playerSel = keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the height for this character: ");
      newHeight = keyboard.nextInt();
      if (newHeight < 125 && newHeight > 240)
      {
        System.out.println("WRONG! TRY AGAIN!");
      }
      else
      {

      }
    } while (newHeight >= 125 && newHeight <= 240);
  }

  public static void BubbleSort(ArrayList<Player> S){
    Player strTemp;
    int i = 0;
    boolean isSorted = false;
    while(i < S.size()&&isSorted==false)
    {
      isSorted = true;
      for(int j = 0; j < (S.size()-1)-i;j++)
      {
        if(S.get(j).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(S.get(j+1).getName())>0){
          strTemp = S.get(j);
          S.set(j,S.get(j+1));
          S.set(j+1,strTemp);
          isSorted = false;
        }
      }  
      i++;}
  }
  public static void InsertionSort(ArrayList<Player> S){  // hits over atbats
    int outer;
    double inner;
    for(outer = 1; outer < S.size();outer++){
     double keyItem = S.get(outer).getBatAvg();
      inner = outer - 1 ;

      while(inner >0&&S.get(inner-1).getBatAvg() > keyItem){
        S.set((inner),S.get(inner-1));
        inner--;
        break;
      }
      double helpSort = S.get(inner).getBatAvg();
      helpSort = keyItem; 
    }
  }

}
class PlayerRip {
  public String name;
  public String name2;
  public String position;
  public int [ ] mark = new int[7];
  public double [ ] batAvg = new double[1]; 


  static class PlayerInfo extends PlayerRip
  {
    PlayerInfo() { 
      this.name = "-1";
      this.name2 = "-1";
      this.position = "-1";
      for (int i=0; i < mark.length; i++)
        mark[i] = -1;
    }

    PlayerInfo(String nam, String nam2, String pos, int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, double h)  {
      this.name = nam;
      this.name2 = nam2;
      this.position = pos;
      this.mark[0] = a;  this.mark[1] = b;  this.mark[2] = c; this.mark[3] = d; this.mark[4] = e; this.mark[5] = f; this.mark[6] = g; 
      batAvg[0] = (((double)mark[1] / (double)mark[2]) * 100);
    } 

    public void setName(String nam) { name = nam; }
    public void setName2(String nam2) { name2 = nam2; }
    public void setPosition(String pos) { position = pos; }
    public void setMark(int index, int mark) { this.mark[index] = mark; }
    public void setBatAvg(int index, double batAvg) {this.batAvg[index] = batAvg;}
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public String getName2() { return this.name2; }
    public String getPosition() { return this.position; }
    public double getBatAvg() { return this.batAvg[0];}
    public int getMark(int index) { return this.mark[index]; }
    public void setHeight(int index, int mark) { this.mark[index] = mark; }
    public int getHeight(int index) { return this.mark[0]; }

    public void setHits (int index, int mark) { this.mark [index] = mark; }
    public int getHits (int index) { return this.mark [1]; }
    public void setAtBats (int index, int mark) { this.mark [index] = mark; }
    public int getAtBats(int index) { return this.mark [2]; }
    public void setSingles (int index, int mark) { this.mark [index] = mark; }
    public int getSingles (int index) { return this.mark [3] ; }
    public void setDoubles (int index, int mark) { this.mark [index] = mark; }
    public int getDoubles (int index) { return this.mark [4] ; }
    public void setTriples (int index, int mark) { this.mark [index] = mark; }
    public int getTriples (int index) { return this.mark [5] ; }
    public void setHomeRuns (int index, int mark) { this.mark [index] = mark; }
    public int getHomeRuns (int index) { return this.mark [6] ; }




  } 


}
```

sorry for format im new to the site

```
  }
  public static void InsertionSort(ArrayList<Player> S){  // hits over atbats
    int outer;
    double inner;
    for(outer = 1; outer < S.size();outer++){
     double keyItem = S.get(outer).getBatAvg();
      inner = outer - 1 ;

      while(inner >0&&S.get(inner-1).getBatAvg() > keyItem){
        S.set((inner),S.get(inner-1));
        inner--;
        break;
      }
      double helpSort = S.get(inner).getBatAvg();
      helpSort = keyItem; 
    }
  }

}
```

is the specific area of problems

Answer (score 0):

`S.get()` and `S.set()` take a int variable so cast inner to a int.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `inner` as a `double`, and in Java, when you do math with a `double` and an `int` (such as `inner - 1`), you'll get a `double` as a result. [This page](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/04/mixed.html) has a fairly good explanation.

Then when you say `S.get(inner - 1)`, you're saying to use a `double` as an the index in the ArrayList. The [documentation for ArrayList.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) says that you can only use an `int` as an index, and that's why you're getting a compiler error. You're also only allowed to use an `int` as the index for `set`, so that's why the compiler would complain about `S.set(inner, ...)`.

You could just cast `inner` to an `int`, but it would be much better to declare it as an `int` in the first place since there's no reason it needs to be a `double`.

Comment: i tried declaring them as int but the insertion sort does not work

Comment: i get 0 errors but it doesn't work, is there any other way to use insertion sort for organizing them from highest to lowest batting avg.

Comment: A couple things to get you started... Take a look at your `while` loop. As it's written right now, it will only run once. It also looks like your `helpSort` variable isn't doing anything useful.